# VueJS/Quasar: How do I pass data fetched from FirebaseDB in "mounted" function and use it in "data" so I can display it in my HTML

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, quasar

**myjfc** is a variable that contains the data from my Firebase DB. I don't know how to pass it around - pass it to **data** so I can display it in my DOM.

```
data(){

   return{

       question1: "I_WANT_TO_ASSIGN_DATA_FROM_FIREBASE_HERE"
    }
},

mounted(){  
        this.$firebase.database().ref('questions').on('value', data => {
        const obj = data.val()
        var myjfc = obj.question1.a

        return myjfc //this contains the data I want to use
   })
 }
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if anyone is encountering this, with help from Quasar community @Robin, here's how:

```
data(){
   return{
       question1: ''
    }
},

mounted(){  
        this.$firebase.database().ref('questions').on('value', data => {
        const obj = data.val()
        this.question1 = obj.question1.a
   })
 }
```

Can't believe I missed that!